# Add bibliography with usepackage{biblatex}+addbibresource+printbibliography: not working in Texmaker, working in ShareLatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, code, thesis

I wrote the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\title{\textbf{Template}}
\date{\vspace{-10ex}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Ciao\cite{sun2016multi}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the file bibliografia.bib:

```
@article{sun2016multi,
  title={A multi-technique reconfigurable electrochemical biosensor: enabling personal health monitoring in mobile devices},
  author={Sun, Alexander and Venkatesh, AG and Hall, Drew A},
  journal={IEEE transactions on biomedical circuits and systems},
  volume={10},
  number={5},
  pages={945--954},
  year={2016},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

It works in ShareLatex, but not works in Texmaker. How can I fix it?

Before compiling file.tex, I clicked on strumenti->biblatex.

[image]

Texmaker shows me the following error message:

```
Process started
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Es bibliografia.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Es bibliografia.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Es bibliografia.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Es bibliografia.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: By default, the backend for `biblatex` is `biber`. If you  absolutely want to use `bibtex`  (losing some functionalities of biblatex), use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` in your preamble.

Comment: `biblatex` wants you to run Biber and not BibTeX. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 to see how you can get TeXstudio to run Biber for you instead of BibTeX. In particular I would not advise to go for `backend=bibtex`, that should only be a last resort if you have good reasons to use BibTeX (I'm not saying there are no good reasons, just that the average user should be using Biber).

Comment: Do I need another software called biber if I want to use biber instead of bibtex?

Comment: Yes, Biber needs to be installed on your system. Usually it should come with your TeX distribution, but you can check as follows (on Windows). (1) Press Win+R, a small window should open, (2) type `cmd` and press enter, (3) a command line should open, type in `biber --version` and press enter. (4) If Biber is installed you should see a version information after a while (do *not* close the window or abort the process otherwise if the message does not appear directly, it may take a while) - if Biber is not installed you get an message right away. If Biber is installed follow the link above.

Comment: Hello @moewe I have biber 2.7; i'm using the commands \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}, but the compiler dies not work (I followed the instructions of the above link). If I try to compile the file.bib with biber, Texmaker shows me the error: ERROR - Cannot find control file 'bibliografia.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1

Comment: Do not compile the `.bib` file. Go to the main `.tex` file. Then run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX all on the main file. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864, you never run BibTeX or Biber on the `.bib` file it is always the basename of the `.tex` file.

Comment: @moewe, I did it and I got: 
INFO - This is Biber 2.7 INFO - Logfile is 'Es bibliografia.blg' INFO - Reading 'Es bibliografia.bcf' ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3. This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.11) versions are incompatible. See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation. INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: The message says it all: Your versions of `biblatex` and Biber do not match. Make an update, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864

Comment: Thank you @moewe, I'll update the system later because I read that it can cause some problem.

Comment: It is a wise decision to hold off updating if you have a tight deadline to meet, but if you have not there is not a lot to be gained by waiting. Like this you certainly won't be able to use `biblatex`.

Comment: Is there anything we can do here? The main problems seems to have been getting Biber to run instead of BibTeX (which would make this question a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). The version issue would be easily solved by updating, so there is no real answer in it.

Comment: Anything we can do here? If nothing happens here soon I will vote to close as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: Hello @moewe, have I to delete it?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know if there is anything else we can do here, or if we can just close it as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: @moewe ok, you can classify it as a duplicate.

Comment: Your wish is my command ;-)

Comment: @moewe well done:)